# How we can send value from one form to another form in textbox in C#

Tags: textbox

i am developing windows application in C#.

my requirement is in First form i have multiple textbox like name,id,patient etc.. if i search by id, name and patient information will show in form1, or if i search by name, id and patient information will show. it is working in my first form.. now i have second form where there is only one textbox, which should suppose to show the value i entered to search in first form. 
(i.e suppose i search information using id. then id should show in second form textbox. or if i search information using name. then name should show in second form textbox.)

Please Help! i am searching it for past 3 days but not getting how to do.

Thank You.

Comment: Check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7e9f80c-5144-4ad9-aa5e-7803363ae0cd/passing-variables-between-forms), it will give you some tips to pass data between forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Session["VALUE"] = TextBox1.Text;
TextBox2.Text = Session["VALUE"].ToString();
```

Comment: It is not good, to save this in a Session. And it is not Type Save!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Transfer your Object:

**Second Form Constructor:**

```
private Form _parentForm;
public Form2(Form form) {
    _parentForm= form;
}
```

**First Form call to Second Form**

```
var mySecondForm = new Form2(this);
mySecondForm.Show();
```

**Access from Second Form**

You can access all visible Properties/Fields/Methods from ParentForm this Way

```
_parentForm.MyTextbox.Text = "Foo";
```

Maybe you want to have a Property in the First Form:

```
public TextBox MyTextBox {
    get {
        return _myTextBox;
    }
    set {
        _myTexBox = myTextBox;
    }
}
```

Make Sure `MyTextbox` is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a custom Constructor and a Global Variable in the form you want to bring in the value.

```
            public class YourReceivingForm:Form
            {

             private string GlobalVariable;
            public YourReceivingForm(string Text)
            {
            IntializeComponenet();
            GlobaleVariable=Text;

            }

            private void F_Invoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               YourTextBox.Text = GlobalVariable;
            }
```

now the form from which you are sending value will have a code something like this on any event you want

```
 YourReceivingForm fm = new YourReceivingForm(YourSendingTextBox.Text);
 fm.Show();
```